# Backing up a deduplicated BTRFS filesystem

Tags: btrfs, deduplication

I have some long-term data in a BTRFS volume. I've been using [`btrfs-dedupe`](https://github.com/wellbehavedsoftware/btrfs-dedupe) to deduplicate my data and I'm able to save a tremendous amount of disk space between filesystem compression and deduplication.

To meet my organization's redundancy requirements, I need this data to be stored in multiple locations. Until now, `rsync` has been helpful in replicating the stored data to other media.

Deduplication takes a very long time, given the size of my dataset (a handful of terabytes, so it's not ridiculously large, but still large enough that deduplication takes days). I imagine that if I simply `rsync` files between media, I'll lose all of the deduplication that has been done, as I'm doing deduplication offline.

Is there a way for me to backup this filesystem to another device without having to redo deduplication?

Comment: https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Incremental_Backup

Comment: The fact that there's not a lot of info on this, probably means that you don't want to do this without a thorough understanding of the code... if you value your data :-(

Comment: I'm still researching this, but so far the deduplicating program zbackup actually performs better than any live fs based solution like zfs, vdo, and btrfs and I'm considering just using that for backups, instead.